# Best reference material or app for creating a workout regimine to loose weight?

Tags: weight-loss, bodyweight-exercises, weights

I am really looking for a bible of working out. I have a home gym but nothing too complicated. So I really need something that will help me get started.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Muscle and Strength. They have articles specifically for fat loss.

https://www.muscleandstrength.com/workouts/fat-loss

Comment: Pointing to a link does not really answer the question.  Adding an explanation to support the link would help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a definition of "Bible of working out" better than the marvellous, free site [EXRX](http://www.exrx.net/).

As a suggestion, you may want to start by having a look at their [Beginner's page](http://www.exrx.net/Beginning.html), or go directly to [Exercise Instruction](http://www.exrx.net/Exercise.html) and learn about designing your own workout.

A much simpler, yet very nice source of honest information about working out at home is [Scooby's Workshop](http://scoobysworkshop.com/). He has done a lot of videos that are freely available in Youtube. In particular, he suggests his [home workout plans](http://scoobysworkshop.com/home-workout-plans/) with minimal equipment divided into three categories depending on your fitness level.

Beware of sites sponsored by supplements companies. They may lead you into unrealistically high volume workouts (too many exercises, too often) so that you are compelled to feel that you need the help of supplements to cope with the demands imposed on your body.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged your post with bodyweight-exercises, you can look at this great plan [here](https://fitloop.co/routines/bwf-recommended-beginner-routine), as for a guide, I suggest you go through the /r/bodyweight [FAQ](https://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness/wiki/training_guide). If you want more information on exercises and training, check out exrx.net, which is great source for a lot of training and nutrition information.